# How to call Google API from AWS Lambda (Deployed via Pulumi)

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-api, pulumi

I have a simple web application guarded by Google OAuth. So user has to login using her custom domain google account.
Google responds with a  token, which the application can use. It contains user email, name, etc...

On a serverless backend is AWS Lambda, which in turn calls Google API. The website sends the google token to AWS, which sends it to Google API in header `Authentication: Bearer ${token}`.

Problem is, that Google API always returns error "Invalid credentials"

I have made sure that, the scope for the token contains access to given API, so by my guess it should work.
What am I missing?

PS: The deployment to AWS Infra is implemented as Pulumi script.

Sample code to ilustrate

```javascript
const payload = JSON.stringify({ ... some object ... });

const options = {
        host: 'www.googleapis.com',
        path: '/admin/directory/v1/users',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': payload.length.toString(),
            // Token is obtained from browser, but used in context of AWS lambda
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token.token_id}`
        }
    };

return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    try {
        let body = new Array<Buffer>();
        const request = https.request(options, function (res: any) {

            if (res.statusCode != 200) {
                reject(res.statusCode);
            }

            res.on('data', (data: any) => {                
            body.push(data);
            // It seems that the 'request.on('end') is never fired
            // I receive the data in the first batch, and that's it
            resolve(data.toString());
            });
        });

        request.on('end', () => {
            console.error('Request ended');
            // at this point, `body` has the entire request body stored in it as a string
            let result = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
            resolve(result);
        });

        request.on('error', async (err: Error) => {
        console.error('Errooooorrrr request failed');
        reject(err);
        });

        // Write the payload to the body of the request
        if (payload) {
            request.write(payload);
        };

        request.end();
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log('Something unexpected', e);
    }
});
```

Comment: You should probably add some minimal code that would reproduce your problem

Comment: which property from the token object are you using for the Bearer? At a guess, you are being given a Refresh Token which you need to submit to the token endpoint to get an Access Token which is the one you should be using.

Comment: @pinoyyid I am using the `token_id` property. How do I recognize the type of token? The refresh vs access token? I am newbee in this area.

Comment: @MikhailShilkov I have added simplified version of the lambda code

Comment: Dump the token object and paste it into your question. Feel free to slightly obfuscate any sensitive data.